# I would ask you to.. vs I would like to ask you to

Tags: grammar

> (a) I would ask you to forward the document to the associates in New York
>
> (b) I would like to ask you to forward the document to the associates in New York

My understanding was that (b) is the only correct form; (a) can only be used if the speaker has a counterfactual premise in mind, as in "If it were me, I would ask you to forward...." I could come up with a number of situations where (a) might sound natural enough, but at least, (a) does not mean the same thing as (b) under normal circumstances.

Recently, however, I keep receiving emails asking me to do something using the construction (a), and they seem to be intended to convey the meaning of (b). Granted, most of them are from non-English speaking countries, but I see this usage so often it makes me wonder:

Is it acceptable, or at least common, to make a request -- asking someone to do something for you -- using the form "I would ask you to" as in (a) above?

Note:
A few people have pointed out my question aoove might be a duplicate of this question:
[Which dialects of English consider “would” to be a polite form of “will”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222166/which-dialects-of-english-consider-would-to-be-a-polite-form-of-will) .  But that page concerns Indian dialects of English and I do not see any connection, unless this usage of "would" as in (a) only, or at least mainly, is common in India.

Thank you.

Comment: This is really a matter of etiquette rather than use of English. Both are OK. You could also say "Would you...", "Could you...", "Can I ask you to...", "Could I ask you to, "May I ask you to...", etc. All perfectly OK, even if slightly nuanced.

Comment: 'I would ask you to forward the document to the associates in New York' is totally idiomatic and is a hedged-for-politeness version of 'I request that you forward the document ...' This is the 'polite' usage of 'would'.

Comment: And “I would *like* to ask you to...  Is even more hedged since now you aren’t technically even asking, you’re just expressing a preference for asking.

Comment: I would **like** to say that this question is not a duplicate, but it is, so I would **not** say that it is not.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I understand "hedged" here, but to my ear, "I would ask you to" sounds slightly more assertive, and "I would like to ask you to" sounds a little more emotionally detached.  (They both work -- if the other person is reasonably cooperative.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "Common use of **would** before verbs of saying and thinking, to make a 
statement sound less definite": _We **would** ask passengers to have their tickets ready for inspection_

Comment: ...Yes. Already addressed at [the modal verb _would_](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169226/the-modal-verb-would/169242#169242) (and doubtless other threads).